# chain a delay > fadeOut > delay > fadeIn inline with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How could I chain the below with jQuery

```
$('.weekendatbernies').delay('1000').fadeOut('slow').delay('3000').fadeIn('fast');
```

When trying the above; my code omits any time values / and strings.

*And just spazzes out flashing back and forth.*

(P.S. Least amount of code.. is most ideal..)

Comment: What do you mean by "*my code omits any time values / and strings?*" Are you invoking all methods without arguments? `.delay()` requires at least one to have an effect.

Comment: Updated my answer with @JonathanLonowski's insight

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Can you [provide an example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the "*just spazzing out flashing back and forth.*" The snippet you provided should already chain the effects of each method by their use of [queues](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) -- http://jsfiddle.net/hkb6dL9v/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** (Thank you JonathanLonowski)

You have to use numerical values in your fade functions:

```
$('.weekendatbernies').delay('1000').fadeOut(1000).delay('3000').fadeIn(300);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nca5udku/1/

**Previous answer:**
You can also use the `completed` callback (http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) of these animations.

```
$('.weekendatbernies').delay('1000').fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).delay('3000').fadeIn('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nca5udku/

Comment: `.delay()`, `.fadeIn()`, and `.fadeOut()` all make use of the `"fx"` [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) by default. The explicit callback shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Oh yes, indeed. I tried again and it seems to need numerical values instead of `slow` and `fast`